# Woocommerce Product list by IDs return only one product instead multiple selected

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

WooCommerce featured product widget with selected id's but only one product return.

My goal is I have some product ids like `1202,125,2152,885,1254` I need to display them as a list

I make a metabox where i select product and get the ids and store them as `$featured` 
where `$featured` returned  the output like `1202,125,2152,885,1254`.

I use  `$query_args['post__in'] = array($featured);`  but the result output only one product instead of selected 5 products.

Can any one help me with is ?

**Full code**

```
<?php
defined( 'ABSPATH' ) || exit;

class FPW_Widget_Featured_Products extends WC_Widget {


    public function __construct() {
        $this->widget_cssclass    = 'woocommerce widget_products';
        $this->widget_description = __( "A list of your store's products.", 'woocommerce' );
        $this->widget_id          = 'fpw_widget_featured_products';
        $this->widget_name        = __( 'FPW Featured Product', 'woocommerce' );
        $this->settings           = array(
            'title'       => array(
                'type'  => 'text',
                'std'   => __( 'Featured Product', 'woocommerce' ),
                'label' => __( 'Title', 'woocommerce' ),
            ),
            'number'      => array(
                'type'  => 'number',
                'step'  => 1,
                'min'   => 1,
                'max'   => 10,
                'std'   => 5,
                'label' => __( 'Number of products to show from selected', 'woocommerce' ),
            ),

        );
        parent::__construct();
    }
    /**
     * Query the products and return them.
     *
     * @param array $args     Arguments.
     * @param array $instance Widget instance.
     *
     * @return WP_Query
     */
    public function get_products( $args, $instance ) {
        global $post;
        $featured = get_post_meta($post->ID, '_blog_feature_product',true);
        $number              = ! empty( $instance['number'] ) ? absint( $instance['number'] ) : $this->settings['number']['std'];
        $product_term_ids    = wc_get_product_visibility_term_ids();
        $query_args = array(
            'posts_per_page' => $number,
            'post_status'    => 'publish',
            'post_type'      => 'product',
            'meta_query'     => array(),
            'tax_query'      => array(
                'relation' => 'AND',
            ),
        ); // WPCS: slow query ok.

        if ( 'yes' === get_option( 'woocommerce_hide_out_of_stock_items' ) ) {
            $query_args['tax_query'][] = array(
                array(
                    'taxonomy' => 'product_visibility',
                    'field'    => 'term_taxonomy_id',
                    'terms'    => $product_term_ids['outofstock'],
                    'operator' => 'NOT IN',
                ),
            ); // WPCS: slow query ok.
        }

        if ( ! empty( $featured ) && is_array( $featured ) ) {
            $featured = implode( ',', array_map( 'absint', $featured ) );
            $query_args['post__in'] = array($featured);
        }else{
            $query_args['post__in'] = '';
        }   


        return new WP_Query($query_args);
    }
    /**
     * Output widget.
     *
     * @param array $args     Arguments.
     * @param array $instance Widget instance.
     *
     * @see WP_Widget
     */
    public function widget( $args, $instance ) {
        if ( $this->get_cached_widget( $args ) ) {
            return;
        }
        ob_start();
        $products = $this->get_products( $args, $instance );

        if ( $products && $products->have_posts() ) {
            $this->widget_start( $args, $instance );
            echo wp_kses_post( apply_filters( 'woocommerce_before_widget_product_list', '<ul class="product_list_widget">' ) );
            $template_args = array(
                'widget_id'   => $args['widget_id'],
                'show_rating' => true,
            );
            while ( $products->have_posts() ) {
                $products->the_post();
                wc_get_template( 'content-widget-product.php', $template_args );
            }
            echo wp_kses_post( apply_filters( 'woocommerce_after_widget_product_list', '</ul>' ) );
            $this->widget_end( $args );
        }
        wp_reset_postdata();
        echo $this->cache_widget( $args, ob_get_clean() ); // WPCS: XSS ok.
    }
}

function fpw_register_featured_products_widgets() {
    register_widget( 'FPW_Widget_Featured_Products' );
}
add_action( 'widgets_init', 'fpw_register_featured_products_widgets' );
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are passing the values to `$featured` variable as an array when using `$featured = get_post_meta($post->ID, '_blog_feature_product',true);`
Then you don't need to use this

```
$featured = implode( ',', array_map( 'absint', $featured ) ); 
$query_args['post__in'] = array($featured);
```

Instead simply use this:

```
$query_args['post__in'] = $featured;
```

And if the values passes to `$featured` as comma separated i.e `$featured = "1,2,3,4,5";`

Then use this

```
$query_args['post__in'] = explode( ",", $featured);
```

This should work fine now.

Comment: `'terms'    => 'featured',` will show default featured product . how ever thanks for your answer

Comment: ok. I tested your code on localserver. Seems you have some issue with values passed to $featured variable.

Comment: I have edited my code above explaining the issue. Let me know if that fixes it. I tested it on my end and works fine.